# Calling multiple list of item in View using Tuple in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i am using 4 List at view then its working properly means in my example if i am using till PreClearanceDetail its working properly for all four list but after 5th one added that is FAQ its showing below compliation error.

Kindly guide for the same because as per my knowledge tuple can take N number of arguments.
My controller code is :

```
 [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult AdminDashboard()
            {
              DB_Entities entities = new DB_Entities();
              List<Menu> MenuVM= entities.Menu.ToList();
              List<TradeClose> tradeclose = entities.TradeCloses.ToList();
              List<NonComplianceCas> cases = entities.NonComplianceCases.ToList();
              List<PreClearanceDetail> data = entities.PreClearanceDetails.Where(a => a.Flag == ull).ToList();
              List<FAQ> faqs = entities.FAQs.ToList();
              List<Annoucement> Annoucements = entities.Annoucements.ToList();
               return View(Tuple.Create(Menu, tradeclose, cases, data , faqs));
            }
```

My View code is :

```
@model  Tuple<List<MenuVM>, List<TradeClose>, List<NonComplianceCas>, List<PreClearanceDetail> ,List<FAQ>>
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a documented limitation, but at the point you're creating a tuple of five lists, aren't you better off creating a viewmodel?

Comment: I am using Tuple list as i want to show data in table and want to do crud operations on table itself.